# Evidently AI Multiclass Metrics: setting average

Tags: python, metrics, evidently

I am using Evidently AI for a multiclass classification model. When I ran the performance report:

```
performance_report = Report(metrics=[
ClassificationQualityMetric()
])

performance_report.run(reference_data=reference, current_data=valid,
                    column_mapping=column_mapping)
```

I get the following error:

```
  ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another 
  average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

I understand the error but I don't know where to modify the setting for the average to make it 'weighted' or 'macro'

When I use sklearn classification metrics, I can modify the average settings, but with Evidently AI I have no idea where to make the modification.